# Draw two surfaces side by side in one figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two surfaces in MATLAB that I would like to plot side-by-side in the same window.

After searching on Mathworks, it seems like the hold command is what I needed, so I tried this (as well as several variants):

```
    surf(1:200,1:200,autism_mat(1:200,1:200));
    title('Autism Group')

    hold on;

    surf(1:200,1:200,control_mat(1:200,1:200));
    title('Control Group')
```

But the last plot just replaces the first. It seems that I'm missing something simple, I didn't think it would be difficult to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add offset to x or y coordinate in the second surface.

```
surf(1:200,1:200,autism_mat(1:200,1:200));
title('Autism Group')

hold on;

surf([1:200] + 250,1:200,control_mat(1:200,1:200));
title('Control Group')
```

Or you can plot them as subplots:

```
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
lines = surf(1:200,1:200,rand(200,200));
title('Autism Group')

subplot(1,2,2);

surf(1:200,1:200,rand(200,200));
title('Control Group')
```

Comment: Thanks! This plots both surfaces in the same coordinate system, I would prefer to create a second coordinate system for the second surface. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: @drautskis I added example of plotting them as subplots. Hope this is what you are after.